# JavaScript - style.display not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get away from jQuery crutches and refactoring the bellow functions as plain JS.

```
 //slide toggle navigation 
 $('#nav-toggle').click(function () {
     $('.nav-list').slideToggle();
 });

   //toggle hamburger menu 
 $('#nav-toggle').click(function () {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
 });
```

I got the last one working as:

```
   const toggle = document.getElementById('nav-toggle');
   const navList = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-list');  

    toggle.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    this.classList.toggle('active'); //toggle hamburger menu 
    e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```

I hit a blocker when I tried to pass both functionalities to the same click event:

```
//Add a click event listener
toggle.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    //show hide div
    if (navList.style.display == 'none') {
        navList.style.display === 'block';
    } else {
        navList.style.display === 'none';
    }    

    this.classList.toggle('active');
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

I have `.nav-list` as display none in my `CSS`.

Do I need separate event listeners for each event? 
I tried that, but the error is still the same = `TypeError: navList.style is undefined`

Also, what would be the refactor for this nasty one bellow as plain JS?

```
 $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function (e) {
        $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
        // Close one dropdown when selecting another
        $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: Your DOM is not ready! Use JavaScript at the end of body or use `window.onload` or an EventListener to check if your html can be accessed.

Comment: `navList.style.display === 'block';` you have a typo, I assume you meant to assign here using `=` and not compare?

Comment: `navList` is a `NodeList`, not a single element.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns you a `NodeList`. Try `document.querySelector('.nav-list')` instead.

Comment: It is unlikely that the error is exactly: `navList.style is not defined`. It's probably something like: `Cannot set style of undefined`. Please check and post the exact error.

Comment: @ScottMarcus TypeError: navList.style is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're out of jQuery, but you're still thinking in jQuery. `navList` is a NodeList object now, you need to iterate:

```
//Add a click event listener
toggle.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    //show hide div
    for( var i = 0; i < navList.length; ++i ){
        if (navList[i].style.display == 'none') {
            navList[i].style.display === 'block';
        } else {
            navList[i].style.display === 'none';
        }    
    }
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Edit:
This monstrosity *should* do the other fuction's job:

```
(function(){
    var navDropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-dropdown');
    var nav = document.getElementsByTagName('nav');
    for( var i = 0; i < nav.length; ++i ){
        var ul = nav[i].getElementsByTagName('ul');

        for( var j = 0; j < ul.length; ++j ){
            var li = ul[j].getElementsByTagName('li');

            for( var m = 0; m < li.length; ++m ){
                var a = li[m].getElementsByTagName('a');

                if( a.length > 0 ){
                    for( var k = 0; k < a.length; ++k ){
                        a[k].addEventListener('click', (function(a){
                                return function(e){
                                    for( var n = 0; n < a.length; ++n ){
                                        a[n].classList.toggle('nav-dropdown');
                                    }   

                                    for( var o = 0; o < navDropdown.length; ++o ){
                                        var found = false;
                                        for( var n = 0; n < a.length; ++n ){
                                            if( navDropdown[o] === a[n] ){
                                                found = true;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if( !found ){
                                            navDropdown[o].classList.add('hide');
                                        }
                                    }

                                    e.preventDefault();
                                };
                            })(a)
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

It might very possibly be one of the worst things I've ever written, but it *should* work...
Obviously I can't check if it does without the actual page, but at least it runs.

Comment: It is, you're right. Same thing for this use though.

Comment: No it is not, since NodeList doesn't support generic array methods (forEach is an exception).

Comment: @Teemu I believe they mean you can still use a for loop to iterate it (which iirc you can)

Comment: Yep, and you can even iterate using `forEach` method, but it's still not an array, and you should not call it "array", because it confuses those who aren't aware about the nodeList object. Next they are trying to filter the elements in the nodeList, and then come here asking "Why not filter works in array" ...

Comment: @Demonblack Thank you. So let me get this straight. It is a NodeList object rather than an array? also how would I refactor the last jQuery function?

Comment: @Teemu totes agreed there, I don't even like calling them "array-like"

Comment: @tonkihonks13 Yes, it's a NodeList (HTMLCollection in firefox's console).I edited the answer with something that should do the other function's work, assuming you have a CSS class called `hide` to do the hiding.

Comment: This is something which really is living, the name of the object has been changed several times during the last couple of years. `gEBCN` really returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), where as `.querySelectorAll` currently returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). HTMLCollection doesn't have `forEach` method, but NodeList does have it.

Answer (score 2):

you can iterate over a node list by using Array.from which will treat it as an array.

```
Array.from(navList).forEach(function(navItem){
  navItem.style.display = navItem.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
})
```

Comment: Awesome  conciseness!

Comment: `[...navList]` is also a sweet way to convert it

Answer (score 1):

You have the equal signs in your syntax crossed, should be:

```
if (navList.style.display === 'none') {
    navList.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    navList.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Quick cheat sheet:

= : *assign*

== : *equals* (also crosses javascript "type borders", i.e. 0 == "0" is true)

=== : *strict equals* (0 === "0" is false, 0 === 0 is true)

Comment: @Demonblack is still correct about the iteration, though, since the getElementsByClassName returns a collection.